# How to construct data frame from Web Scraping in Python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests, tabulate

I can fetch data from web page thru web scraping in Python. My data is fetched into a list. But don't know how to transform that list into a data frame. Is there any way I could web scrape and fetch data directly to a df?
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate
from pandas import DataFrame
import lxml

# GET the response from the web page using requests library
res = requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")

# PARSE and fetch content using BeutifulSoup method of bs4 library
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
df = pd.read_html(str(table))

# Here dumping the fetched data to have a look
print( tabulate(df[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql') )
print(df[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
df = pd.read_html(r.content)[0]

print(type(df))

# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/09b5ddcc69ed9206b54e40a0d4c950e6/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Very straight forward, learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

Well `read_html` returns a *list of DataFrames* (as per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html)), so you have to get the "first" (and only) element of that list.

I would just add at the end (after you call `read_html`):

```
df = df[0]
```

Then you can inspect its info getting:

```
df.info()

# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# RangeIndex: 207 entries, 0 to 206
# Data columns (total 10 columns):
# Country,Other       207 non-null object
# TotalCases          207 non-null int64
# NewCases            59 non-null object
# TotalDeaths         144 non-null float64
# NewDeaths           31 non-null float64
# TotalRecovered      154 non-null float64
# ActiveCases         207 non-null int64
# Serious,Critical    112 non-null float64
# Tot Cases/1M pop    205 non-null float64
# Deaths/1M pop       142 non-null float64
# dtypes: float64(6), int64(2), object(2)
# memory usage: 16.3+ KB
```

Comment: I could select only one solution, and both of solutions works for me. Thanks anyway.