# Python: (BeautifulSoup) Requesting Info with Class Gives Me '[ ]'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When requesting a website using class='even', I end up just receiving '[]' as my result.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.findAll('tr', class_='even'))
```

This is my result

```
[]
```

I tried looking in a lot of places but I couldn't find out why. The HTML code is really long as there is a lot of data.

Comment: can't see any tr with that class in the html, nor any "even" class, actually...

Comment: A quick inspection of the webpage shows no tr with the class="even". I may have missed it but could you tell me what element data you are trying to target?

Comment: To the bottom of the webpage, there is a table with the infection count. The code for the table is a <tr> code with the classes 'even' or 'odd' depending on the location of the row in the table.

Comment: @ShashwathThiyagarajan check my answer below

Comment: Are you trying to extract the table?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to extract the table, but I finished it. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this is the universal solution, but this is what worked for my project. I used @ahmedamerican's solution with a few changes in order to fix it.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import lxml

r = requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
df = pd.read_html(r.content)[0]

print(df)
```

Just instead of doing `print(type(df))` as he said, I did `print(df)`.

Comment: my answer was actually guiding you to `print(df)`, i just was shown the type of the object to let you understand it's a `dataframe`, also you don't need to import `lxml`. it's already included within `pandas` library. However my answer has been deleted by the `Moderator` because it's count as duplicated, as I've answered the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008195/how-to-construct-data-frame-from-web-scraping-in-python/61008983#61008983) before.