# How can i scrape table rows for Top Gainers and Top Losers from Finviz.com with Python and BeautifulSoup or Pandas?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, stock

This is as far as I have gotten. How can i scrape table rows for Top Gainers  and Top Losers from Finviz.com with Python and BeautifulSoup or Pandas?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r=requests.get("https://finviz.com")
c=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

table =soup.find("table", {"class": "t-home-table"})
table_rows = table.find_all("tr")


for tr in table_rows:
 td = tr.find_all("td")
 row = [i.text for i in td]
 print(row)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to construct data frame from Web Scraping in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008195/how-to-construct-data-frame-from-web-scraping-in-python)

Comment: You already have the first table. To get the second one, just use soup,find_all("table", ...) and the first two items will be the tables you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could just cycle through all tables and then pick out the rows with the required signal type. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("https://finviz.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for table in soup.find_all("table", {"class": "t-home-table"}):
    print()

    for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
        td = tr.find_all("td")
        row = [i.text for i in td]

        if len(row) > 5 and row[5] in ['Top Gainers', 'Top Losers']:
            print(row)
```

This would display:

```
['MBRX', '1.27', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Gainers']
['EFC', '9.12', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Gainers']
['NYMTP', '14.90', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Gainers']
['I', '1.65', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Gainers']
['NYMTO', '14.80', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Gainers']
['NYMTM', '14.43', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Gainers']
['XAN', '2.99', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Gainers']

['YGYI', '1.90', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Losers']
['DPW', '1.24', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Losers']
['EDRY', '4.52', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Losers']
['INVE', '2.76', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Losers']
['EHTH', '103.20', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Losers']
['SPTN', '12.66', '0.00%', '0', '', 'Top Losers']
```

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer as the accepted solution to your question. Click the grey tick under the up/down buttons to accept it.